# Entire post linking to actual article. How?

Tags: wordpress, post

Im just starting to theme on the Bones "framework", and i'd like to make the frontpage article previews link to the post, instead of just the `<h1>`linking.

How do i acheive this? Making the entire preview link a clickable div?

Here is the mockup for that section! :)

```
<article id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class('clearfix'); ?> role="article">

                            <header class="article-header">

                                <h1 class="h2"><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" rel="bookmark" title="<?php the_title_attribute(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h1>

                                <p class="byline vcard"><?php _e('Posted', 'bonestheme'); ?> <time class="updated" datetime="<?php echo the_time('Y-m-j'); ?>" pubdate><?php the_time(get_option('date_format')); ?></time> <?php _e('by', 'bonestheme'); ?> <span class="author"><?php the_author_posts_link(); ?></span> <span class="amp">&</span> <?php _e('filed under', 'bonestheme'); ?> <?php the_category(', '); ?>.</p>

                            </header> <!-- end article header -->

                            <section class="entry-content clearfix">
                                <?php the_content(); ?>
                            </section> <!-- end article section -->
```

Answer (score 0):

You can always use a *JavaScript* solution combined with a *CSS*:

```
<article style="cursor:pointer;" onclick="window.location='<?php the_permalink(); ?>'">
  ...
</article>
```

Answer (score 0):

not sure if it complies with the HTML5 specs , but you can try moving the  to wrap all the article ..:

```
    <article id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class('clearfix'); ?> role="article">

<!-- move <a> to here -->

<a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" rel="bookmark" title="<?php the_title_attribute(); ?>">

                                <header class="article-header">

                                    <h1 class="h2"><?php the_title(); ?> </h1>

                                    <p class="byline vcard"><?php _e('Posted', 'bonestheme'); ?> <time class="updated" datetime="<?php echo the_time('Y-m-j'); ?>" pubdate><?php the_time(get_option('date_format')); ?></time> <?php _e('by', 'bonestheme'); ?> <span class="author"><?php the_author_posts_link(); ?></span> <span class="amp">&</span> <?php _e('filed under', 'bonestheme'); ?> <?php the_category(', '); ?>.</p>

                                </header> <!-- end article header -->

                                <section class="entry-content clearfix">
                                    <?php the_content(); ?>
                                </section> <!-- end article section -->
<!-- close </a>  here -->
    </a>
```